# ng-click not working for anchor tag in internet explorer after adding href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have below anchor tag

```
    <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-      
    transclude="heading">
```

and toggleOpen function is getting triggered on ng-click as expected.However when I add href to the above anchor tag as

```
    <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-      
    transclude="heading">
```

toggleOpen() function is not getting triggered,even I tried the below combinations:

```
   1) <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); toggleOpen()" accordion-      
    transclude="heading">

   2)<a href="" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); toggleOpen()" accordion-      
    transclude="heading">

   3)<a ng-href="#" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); toggleOpen()" accordion-      
    transclude="heading">
```

May I know how we can make toggleOpen() get triggered, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you specify version of IE and make fiddle for it?

Comment: Hi Stevar the IE version is 11., I will fiddle for it

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: no error in console Jai , i put a breakpoint in the debugger console in ie, without href break point is getting executed, with hef it is not

Comment: so, when you click the anchor tag, nothing is triggered (if u specify link for anchor tag), right?

Comment: but for me its working. When i specify the link in anchor tag, the toggleOpen() function is called and i am redirect to that specified page

Comment: @Thinker is it working in ie?,can you give me that line of code please

Comment: check this. http://plnkr.co/edit/01WdkbsGXvaqJtwSzpsP?p=preview see whether it is working or not?

Comment: @Thinker, in splunker it is working

Comment: Then refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154088/angularjs-ng-href-doesnt-work-in-ie8 Might help you

Answer (score 1):

Are you using routes in your application. If you are then href will redirect you to same page again . if you are using ngroute then in your app.run you can use route change event:

```
app.run($rootScope,function(){
     $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                  if(next == '#' || next.indexOf('#') == -1) {

                   event.preventDefault();
                   }
});
```

})

Comment: Hi Manij thanks for the answer, in my application Im not using routes